# JS slice a nested array in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array structure:

```
  const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
      {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I need to `splice(0, 3)` a nested `data` array.

Here's what I tried so far, but I need to get the same output as the input array with sliced `data`:

```js
  const mockData = [
    {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
        { field: '5' },
        { field: '6' }
      ]
    },
      {
      text: 'Text1',
      data: [
        { field: '1' },
        { field: '2' },
        { field: '3' },
        { field: '4' },
      ]
    }
  ];


const slicedArray = mockData.reduce((accumulator, arr) => {
  const spliceData = arr.data.splice(0, 3);

  accumulator.push(spliceData);

  return accumulator;
}, []);


console.log(slicedArray)
```

What's the simplest way to achieve it? Thank you!

Comment: please add the wanted result. btw, `splice` mutates the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
const mockData = [{text:"Text1",data:[{field:"1"},{field:"2"},{field:"3"},{field:"4"},{field:"5"},{field:"6"}]},{text:"Text1",data:[{field:"1"},{field:"2"},{field:"3"},{field:"4"}]}];

const slicedArray = mockData.map(d => ({...d, data: d.data.slice(0, 3)}))
console.log(slicedArray)
```